# SvelteKit/Supabase Type 'Session | null' is not assignable to type 'Session'

Tags: typescript, sveltekit, supabase

**tl:dr**

This is the error I'm getting in VS Code:

```
let session: AuthSession
    Type 'Session | null' is not assignable to type 'Session'.
    Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Session'.ts(2322)
```

This is the script code:

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { onMount } from "svelte";
    import { supabase } from "../../supabaseClient";
    import type { AuthSession } from "@supabase/supabase-js";
    import Account from "../../lib/Account.svelte";
    import Auth from "../../lib/Auth.svelte";

    let session: AuthSession;

    onMount(() => {
        supabase.auth.getSession().then(({ data }) => {
            session = data.session;
        });

        supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange((_event, _session) => {
            session = _session;
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Background info:**

I'm trying to learn Sveltekit and Supabase, and I know that Sveltekit just released a breaking update, so I don't know if that's why I can't find any fixes to this, but I started with the Quickstart guide on [Supabase.com](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/with-svelte) and ran into issues with Sveltekit's routing, so I started a separate [Sveltekit skeleton app](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/introduction#getting-started) and copied over the Supabase code from the quickstart project.

The frustrating thing is that it all works, but I'm getting the error above in all of my `+page.svelte` pages on the line `session = data.session;` and `session = _session;`. Maybe it's an issue I've tried adding lines in `src/app.d.ts` to import the `User` and `AuthSessions` types, but that didn't affect it. I've also tried restarting VS Code, just to see if it was a typing issue in the app, but it's still there.

I'm sure it's something dumb, any and all help would be appreciated, thanks!

Oh, here's the `package.json` file, for versions:

```
{
    "name": "sveltekit-test",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite dev",
        "build": "vite build",
        "preview": "vite preview",
        "check": "svelte-kit sync && svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json",
        "check:watch": "svelte-kit sync && svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json --watch"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@sveltejs/adapter-auto": "next",
        "@sveltejs/kit": "next",
        "svelte": "^3.44.0",
        "svelte-check": "^2.7.1",
        "svelte-preprocess": "^4.10.6",
        "tslib": "^2.3.1",
        "typescript": "^4.7.4",
        "vite": "^3.1.0"
    },
    "type": "module",
    "dependencies": {
        "@supabase/supabase-js": "^2.0.0-rc.10"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using asynchronous functions in onMount the immediate value of your session variable is null.  Then eventually it will have a value that is satisfied by the Session type.

To make this more accurate change the type for your variable declaration to something like:

```
let session: AuthSession | null;
```

This would even work in the error case where you are not able to supply a session.

Comment: Yep, I knew it was something dumb, still learning Typescript as well. Thank you!